# got a 401 when I get access token for LinkedIn

Tags: php, oauth, linkedin-api

$oauth->getAccessToken() causes Invalid auth/bad request (got a 401, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect).

How do I look at the request headers to figure out what exactly is wrong?

```
    $oauth = new OAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

    $oauth->disableSSLChecks();
    $request_token_response = $oauth->getRequestToken('https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken');

    if($request_token_response === FALSE) {
            throw new Exception("Failed fetching request token, response was: " . $oauth->getLastResponse());
    } else {
        $request_token = $request_token_response;
        var_dump($request_token);

        if (!isset($_GET['oauth_verifier'])) {
            $this->redirect("https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" . $request_token['oauth_token']);
        } else {
            $oauth_verifier = $_GET['oauth_verifier'];
            $oauth->setToken($request_token['oauth_token'], $request_token['oauth_token_secret']);

            $access_token_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken';
            $access_token_response = $oauth->getAccessToken($access_token_url, "", $oauth_verifier);

            if($access_token_response === FALSE) {
                    throw new Exception("Failed fetching request token, response was: " . $oauth->getLastResponse());
            } else {
                $access_token = $access_token_response;

                $params = array();
                $headers = array();
                $method = OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_GET;

                // Specify LinkedIn API endpoint to retrieve your own profile
                $url = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~";

                // By default, the LinkedIn API responses are in XML format. If you prefer JSON, simply specify the format in your call
                // $url = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json";

                // Make call to LinkedIn to retrieve your own profile
                $oauth->fetch($url, $params, $method, $headers);

                echo $oauth->getLastResponse();
            }
        }

    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oauth_verifier only verifies the request_token from which it was obtained. I needed to store the original request_token in session instead of getting a new request_token on callback.